# Show only one expand at a time javascript show content with toggle

Tags: javascript, html, show

I found this code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function showHide(elementid){
    if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
      document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div><a href="javascript:showHide('div_1035677');">more...</a></div>
  <div id="div_1035677" style="display:none">
    HIDDEN CONTENT
  </div>
  <div><a href="javascript:showHide('div_1035678');">more...</a></div>
  <div id="div_1035678" style="display:none">
    HIDDEN CONTENT
  </div>
```

Now, it allows people using my website to have all contents expanded. I only want to allow one at a time. So it automatically closes all others if they click a different one. How can you do this in pure js?

Comment: unclear what you are trying to achieve or ask

Comment: why don't you run the code... It allows you to extend multiple at the same time. I only want one extended at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all the divs that you want to automatically close into a class called `hiders` or something and in your `showHide()` function, before making them visible, make all the members of the class invisible. Like this:

```
function showHide(elementid){

    var hiders = document.getElementsByClassName("hiders");
      for(var i =0;i<hiders.length;i++){
        hiders[i].style.display = "none";
      }

    if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
      document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
    }
}

<div><a href="javascript:showHide('div_1035677');">more...</a></div>
<div class="hiders" id="div_1035677" style="display:none">
    HIDDEN CONTENT
</div>
<div><a href="javascript:showHide('div_1035678');">more...</a></div>
<div class="hiders" id="div_1035678" style="display:none">
    HIDDEN CONTENT
</div>
```